# добавить код города к телефонам в определенные ячейки и в соответствии с районом

Tags: python

Есть файл: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1aE1P6pF-_pBfbv0XaZvAWBVskpesNeuu/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=106434889534507496883&rtpof=true&sd=true

[image: Таблица с телефонами и районом.]

Нужно по определенному району добавить к номеру телефона (если длина символов в строке 5) код города. Это не во всех ячейках нужно сделать, а в определенных, где есть номера телефонов с кол-м символов = 5. Где ячейки пустые, пусть будут пустые.

Нашла как добавить код к телефону, но как обратиться к каждой строке и выбрать только те телефоны, которые по кол-ву символов = 5.

Вот мой код:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну а зачем там двоеточие? И код надо текстом прикладывать

Comment: вот код   'for x in lis:
  lis = list(df_tel[df_tel['Телефон_2'].str.len().eq(5)]):
  if x==5:
    df_tel['Телефон_2'] = "884446" + df_tel['Телефон_2']'

Comment: прошу прощения, коряво приложила код. Всё равно не получается.